# Find the convex subdifferential $\partial d_K$ of the distance function $d_K$ associated to a convex set $K$ at in-set points $x_0 \in K$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

**GIVEN**

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a nonempty, closed and convex set. The associated distance function is $d_K$. Find the subdifferential $\partial d_K(x_0)$ for all $x_0 \in K$.

---

**USEFUL DEFINITIONS**

> ***Convex Subdifferential***
>   
>   The subdifferential of a proper, lower semi-continuous, and convex function $f$ at a point $x_0 \in \text{dom}(f)$ is:
>   $$
> \partial f (x_0) = \big\{ z \in \mathbb{R}^n : f(x) \geq f(x_0) + \langle z, x - x_0 \rangle , \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n \big\}
> $$
>   ***Normal Cone***
>   
>   The normal cone of a nonempty, closed, and convex set $K$ at a point $x_0 \in K$ is:
>   $$
> N_K(x_0)=\big\{ z:\langle z, \;x-x_0 \rangle \leq 0,\; \forall x \in K\big\}
> $$

---

**CONTEXT**

After some research I have found out that this is a well-known result: $\partial d_K (x_0) = \bar{B}\cap N_K (x_0)$ for all $x_0 \in K$. Here $\bar{B}$ refers to the closed unit ball.

Note that this is true for Banach spaces. I am unsure of the result in my case. I also cannot use infimal convolution as I have not learned it yet.

However, I could not find any proof of it anywhere, and thus I am trying to prove that $\Vert z \Vert \leq 1$ (giving $z \in \bar{B}$) and that $\langle z, \; x - x_0 \rangle \leq 0$ (giving $z \in N_K(x_0)$). Here $z \in \partial d_K (x_0)$.

---

**ATTEMPT**

Let $x_0$ be a fixed point in $K$.

The distance function $d_K(x) = \inf_{y \in K} \Vert x - y\Vert$ over a convex set $K$ is convex, proper and lower semi-continuous. Since $x_0 \in K$ then $d_K (x_0) = 0$.

Using the above definition, obtain:
$$
\partial d_K (x_0) = \big\{ \zeta \in \mathbb{R}^n : d_K(x) \geq \langle z, \; x - x_0 \rangle , \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n \big\}
$$

**Part 1 — Normal Cone**

***Case 1*:** $x \in K$

Here, $d_K (x) = 0$ and the above equation gives $\partial d_K(x_0)=N_K (x_0)$.

***Case 2*:** $x \notin K$

Here, $d_K (x) = \Vert x - p\Vert > 0$, where $p$ is the projection of $x$ onto $K$.

I am completely stuck here and have tried multiple failed attempts. How can I prove that $z \in N_K (x_0)$?

**Part 2 — Closed Unit Ball**

Since $\Vert x - p \Vert \geq \langle z,\; x-x_0 \rangle$  for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Choose $x = z + x_0$ to obtain:

$$\
\Vert z + x_0 - p \Vert \geq \langle z,\; z \rangle = \Vert z \Vert^2
$$
Since $\Vert z + x_0 - p \Vert \leq \Vert z \Vert + \Vert x_0 - p\Vert$, then obtain:
$$
\Vert z \Vert \leq 1 + \frac{\Vert x_0 - p \Vert}{\Vert z \Vert}
$$
If $x_0 \in \text{bdry}(K)$, then $p = \text{proj}_K (z + x_0) = x_0$ since $z$ is normal (I am unsure of this). Thus the previous inequality gives $\Vert z \Vert \leq 1$.

I have no clue what to do for $x_0 \in \text{int}(K)$.

(Here $\text{int}$ is interior, $\text{bdry}$ is boundary).

---

I am very confused and have put in too much time without any results. Please, any insight is immensely appreciated.

Comment: Can you prove at least an inclusion? $\partial d_K(x_0)\subset N_K(x_0)$ is immediate.

Comment: $\partial d_K(x_0)\subset B_1$ is also clear because $d_K$ is $1$-Lipschitz.

Comment: Of course you can just work with $x_0\in\partial K$, because if $x_0\in\mathop{\mathrm{int}}(K)$ then both $\partial d_K(x_0)$ and $N_K(x_0)$ are empty.

Comment: @Federico  Empty !!!!!   if $x_0 \in  int(K)$ then $ \partial d_k (x_0) = N_K (x_0) = \{0\} $

Comment: @Redshoes right, of course, my bad; I rushed over it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x_0$ belongs to the boundary of $K$, then the subdifferential requested is the intersection of $N_K(x_0)$ and the closed unit ball.

If $x_0$ belongs to the interior of $K$, then it is $\{0\}$.

For completeness, if $x_0$ is outside $K$, then it is $(x_0-P_Kx_0)/d_K(x_0)$.

For proofs, see Bauschke-Combettes *Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator Theory in Hilbert Spaces*, second edition, Example 16.62.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  If $x \notin K$ then $d_K$ is differentiable at $x$.

Let $\bar{x} \in K$ is the unique point projection of $x$ on $K$

Try to prove that it is differentiable at $x$ using definition of differentiability with $ D d_k (x) = \frac{x- \bar{x}}{ \| x- \bar{x} \|} $.

Comment: Not relevant. He is explicitly asking for $x_0\in K$.

Comment: He said he got stuck in case two, I gave him a big hint.  what I'm saying is that in case 2 

$\partial d_k (x_0) = \{   \frac{x_ 0 - \bar{x}}{ \| x_0  - \bar{x} \|} \} $

Comment: But if $x\not\in K$ then $N_K(x)$ has nothing to do with $\partial d_K(x)$

Comment: That's exactly what I said .

Comment: I mean, of course what you say is correct, I just don't see what it has to do with _"Find the convex subdifferential $\partial d_K$ of the distance function $d_K$ associated to a convex set $K$ at in-set points **$x_0 \in K$**."_

Comment: What get from his attempt, he apparently could handle the case 1 (x_0 \in K). or found out solution in book. 
He is saying he got stuck in case 2. This is what I interpret from his question.

Comment: Actually, under the section **ATTEMPT**, he reaches a wrong conclusion also in **Case 1**.

Comment: The wrong conclusion in ***Case 1*** is $\partial d_K (x_0) = N_K (x_0)$? Should it be an inclusion ($\subset$) instead of an equality ($=$)?

Comment: The provided answer is of course correct, and much appreciated. But I am asking about $x_0 \in K$ when $x \notin K$, and not when $x_0 \notin K$. @Redshoes Your solution is perfect for when $x_0 \notin K$ which is not my question

Comment: My entire approach might be incorrect. I might not need to take cases. Any advice on how to correct my approach?